# When Synology NAS down, rsnapshot fills up my root partition

Tags: mount, backup, nas, rsnapshot

I am using rsnapshot to back up my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS workstation to a Synology NAS server. The NAS volume is mounted as /synology using the following entry in /etc/fstab:

```
synologynas.local:/volume1/ubuntubackup /synology  nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

The trouble is that occasionally, the NAS volume is unavailable (e.g., due to software updates being applied on the NAS or it's simply down for some other reason). At such times, rsnapshot starts saving the backups to the /synology directory which is now on the local root partition, and never automatically remounts the NAS volume when the Synology NAS is up and available again. This causes the root partition to quickly fill up. I only realize that this is happening when the root partition is 100% full.

Is there a way to automatically detect that the mounted NAS volume has become unavailable, generate an email alert, stop rsync backups, and once the NAS volume is available again, to automatically remount it and again generate an automated email indicating all is good as well as resume rsnapshot backups? Can this be configured in rsnapshot.conf or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `mountpoint` command. Read `man mountpoint` and do:

```
if [[ mountpoint -q /synology ]] ; then
    prinf "not mounted\n"
else
    prinf "mounted\n"
fi
```

or

If `/synology` is mounted, it's in `/etc/mtab`, and `grep '/synology' /etc/mtab` works, too.

Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.